# Подскажите пожалуйста что означает это свойства?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

Для чего здесь нужны знаки больше и меньше? 
Для чего они предназначены и это как то связано с `List<>`?

Comment: читай про дженерики (generics)...... с чего ты взял, что это как-то связано с `List<>` ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский связано тем, что List<T> тоже generic

Comment: Как вам тут уже подсказали, почитайте про обобщенные типы и всё вопросы сразу отпадут. И это не "больше/меньше" это угловые скобки

Comment: @Grundy какой-то скудный ответ в дубликате